# Using VBA to create/delete chart via a toggle button

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Embarrassed that the code doesn't work, anyhow:

I have the objective of creating a specific chart using VBA via toggle buttons. If the toggle button is selected/pressed, the chart is created and displayed on a specific part of the active sheet.
If the toggle button is deselected, the chart is deleted.

The following is how my worksheet looks like:

[image]

The following is the code I wrote after learning bit of VBA from different blogs, as I don't currently have access to a VBA book. The code piece is for the Google button, named GoogleBtn, and is invoked when the button is clicked.

```
Private Sub GoogleBtn_Click()

Dim mySheet As Workbook
Dim myChart As Chart

Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myChart = mySheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

If GoogleBtn.Value = True Then

myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B8")
myChart.ChartType = xlLine
myChart.Parent.Name = "GoogleChart"

ElseIf GoogleBtn.Value = False Then

myChart.Parent.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

So the problems are:

1. Why does the `delete` method not work in this case? I tried removing the `.Parent` but it still doesn't function.
2. How to place the chart object on a specific part of the sheet, for example at the right of the buttons? I tried using the `incrementLeft` etc. but did not succeed.

Many thanks for the assistance, and if some references are given for further reading, I will be delighted and thankful even more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deletion does work, but it deletes the new chart that you just created, not any previous ones. You can use something like this:

```
Private Sub GoogleBtn_Click()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = mySheet.Shapes("GoogleChart")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If shp Is Nothing Then
        Set shp = mySheet.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered, _
            Left:=GoogleBtn.Left + GoogleBtn.Width + 2, Top:=GoogleBtn.Top, Height:=100, Width:=150)
    End If

    Set myChart = shp.Chart

    If GoogleBtn.Value = True Then

        myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B8")
        myChart.ChartType = xlLine
        shp.Name = "GoogleChart"

    Else

        shp.Delete

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the assistance. If I may ask: you use the shapes object to facilitate deletion of the chart, right? And why was my method deleting the new charts only and not the previously created one?
If you could answer these too (and if you would like to share any URLs for reference), I would be very grateful.

Comment: Correct. Your workflow was: 1. Click button, which adds a chart and sets its data. 2. Click button again, which adds another chart (so there are now 2), then because the togglebutton is not depressed, it deletes the new chart. However there is still 1 chart on the sheet. 3. Click button again, add another chart and set its data (now we have two again). 4. Repeat step 2, but now there will still be 2 charts at the end, and so on.